# How to add Dependency Injection (DI) using Unity MVC 4 in a Non Controller Class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, unity-container

So I am using Unity MVC-4 for achieving Dependency Injection and it works great with my `Controller` classes but as soon as I try to inject in my non controller class, I get the `NullReferenceException` and I can see that my injected objects are not initialized by the framework. I will  give you the corresponding classes that I am using:

`Controller` class (DI works):

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    IMyService _myService;

    #region CTOR
    public HomeController(IMyService myService)
    {
        _myService = myService;
    }
    #endregion
    
    public string GetMyString()
    {
        string mystring=string.Empty;
        
        try
        {
            mystring = _myService.GetMyStringFromDLL();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
            str.AppendLine("Exception in method GetMyString, Error msg: " + ex.Message);
            WriteLog(sb);
        }
        return mystring;
    }
}
```

And if I do the same thing in a non controller method (DI does not work here), I get a `NullReferenceException`:

```
public inteface IMyLogic
{
    string GetMyString();
}

public class MyLogic: IMyLogic
{
    IMyService _myService;

    #region CTOR
    public MyLogic(IMyService myService)
    {
        _myService = myService;
    }
    #endregion
    
    public string GetMyString()
    {
        string mystring=string.Empty;
        
        try
        {
            mystring = _myService.GetMyStringFromDLL();  //Getting NullReferenceException here
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
            str.AppendLine("Exception in method GetMyString, Error msg: " + ex.Message);
            WriteLog(sb);
        }
        return mystring;
    }
}
```

My `BootStrapper.cs` class looks like:

```
public static class Bootstrapper
{

    public static IUnityContainer Initialise()
    {
      var container = BuildUnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType<IMyService , MyService>();
        container.RegisterType<IMyLogic, MyLogic>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));

      return container;
    }

    private static IUnityContainer BuildUnityContainer()
    {
      var container = new UnityContainer();  
      RegisterTypes(container);
      return container;
    }

    public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
    {

    }

}
```

If you see above in the line `container.RegisterType<IMyService , MyService>();`, the interface and its concrete implementation is in a separate module.

And my `Global.asax.cs` is:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    Bootstrapper.Initialise();
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new OfflineActionFilter());
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

How can I inject the `IMyService` in `MyLogic` class?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Dependency Injection outside of a Controller's constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9401859/using-dependency-injection-outside-of-a-controllers-constructor)

Comment: @Rahul Sharma: What is your `Unity.Mvc4` runtime version? Can you expose your `IMyService` and `MyService` definitions, please. Because I put your code in my application (uses Framework v4.5 too) and it is working.

Comment: @Rahul Sharma: According to your problem description the `_myService` field in the `MyLogic` class is `null` (not initialized - put break-point in the debugger and check it). This is means somehow the `MyLogic.GetMyString()` method is called before the `Unity` performed registering the type `MyLogic` mapping with the container. So, first, there is some code that related to problem and it not exposed in this post. Second, try to move two lines `container.RegisterType<IMyService,...>(); container.RegisterType<IMyLogic,...);` to the `Bootstrapper.BuildUnityContainer()` method.

Comment: @Jackdaw As you can see in my Global.asax that `Bootstrapper.Initialise();` is first called to ensure that the container is mapped correctly with my service(s). I tried your other suggestion also and moved my service to `Bootstrapper.BuildUnityContainer()` method but unfortunately the outcome is the same. I get the same error. How I can check the Unity.Mvc4 runtime version? Also exposing my `IMyService` would not have any effect since the error is generated because `_myService` object is being received as null. I have double checked `MyService` logic and everything looks right there.

Comment: @Rahul Sharma: I mean to put break-point inside the `MyLogic(IMyService myService)` constructor and check that this constructor called by Unity before you call the `MyLogic.GetMyString()` method. At least use `WriteLog()` to check the _myService state.

Comment: @Rahul Sharma:  By the way from some reason, the default `Bootstrapper` template has remarks in the `BuildUnityContainer()` method: **// register all your components with the container here**. Not in the `Bootstrapper.Initialise()` method.

Comment: @Rahul Sharma: Where `MyLogic.GetMyString()` method is called from?

Comment: @Jackdaw I have done the above things and the result is the same. In my logs, I get `Exception in getting method GetMyString, Error msg: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` and while applying breakpoint, I can see `_myService` is coming as null. I tried your second point also and the result is the same, there is no difference in the outcome. Regarding Point 3, I have edited the question so it is less confusing.

Comment: @Rahul Sharma: Okay, I see you edited the code and names are less confusing. I'm just trying to clarify. According to your code the `GetMyStringFromDLL()` method part of the `IMyService` intergace. You wrote **"I can see _myService is coming as null"**. So, this means you just need to check that when constructor `public MyLogic(IMyService myService)` is called by DI the parameter `myService` in the constructor is `null`. Can you check in you code that `public MyLogic(IMyService myService)` called before you call `mystring = _myService.GetMyStringFromDLL();`, please.

Comment: @Rahul Sharma: Is it possible that the `MyLogic` class has more than one constructor? Try to apply `[InjectionConstructor]` attribute to the `public MyLogic(IMyService myService)` constructor.

Comment: How are you instantiating MyLogic? Also, unless you have specific need for the HierarchicalLifetimeManager, I'd recommend using TransientLifetimeManager, PerResolveLifetimeManager, or PerThreadLifetimeManager. With HierarchialLifetimeManager, the child container is not always the same as the parent container. https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/ioc/lifetime-manager-in-unity-container

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it did not work in my case. I had to apply a different technique to get this working in my project.

Answer (score 6):

Use attribute [[InjectionConstructor]](http://unitycontainer.org/tutorials/registration/Type/Constructor/annotation.html) to tell the Unity that the `MyLogic` class is dependent on an object which is to be injected in the constructor:

```
[InjectionConstructor]
public MyLogic(IMyService myService)
{
   _myService = myService;
}
```

Actually the `[InjectionConstructor]` is recommended to use when the injected class contains more than one constructor. Therefore, the attribute is used to  resolve the disambiguation. It was just my hypothesis why the `Unity` cannot resolve the required type, because of the question code does not contain all part of the code. But in the test code below the `[InjectionConstructor]` attribute not needed, because of only one constructor is declared.

Here it is the test code.

The `IMyService` interface definition:

```
public interface IMyService
{
    string GetMyStringFromDLL();
}
```

The `ILogic` interface definition:

```
public interface IMyLogic
{
    string GetMyString();
}
```

The `MyLogic` implementation:

```
public class MyLogic : IMyLogic
{
    IMyService _myService;
       
    public MyLogic(IMyService myService)
    {
        _myService = myService;
    }
        
    public string GetMyString()
    {
        var mystring = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            mystring = "MyLogic.GetMyString() -> " + _myService.GetMyStringFromDLL();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {                
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Exception in method MyLogic.GetMyString(): " + ex.Message); 
        }
        return mystring;
    }
}
```

The `MyService` implementation:

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    public string GetMyStringFromDLL()
    {
        return "MyService.GetMyStringFromDLL() is called.";
    }
}
```

The `Bootstrapper` initialization:

```
public static class Bootstrapper
{
    public static IUnityContainer Initialise()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType<IMyService, MyService>();            
        container.RegisterType<IMyLogic, MyLogic>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager()); 
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
        return container;
    }
}
```

The `Home` controller implementation:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IMyService _myService;
    private readonly IMyLogic _myLogic;

    #region CTOR
    public HomeController(IMyService myService, IMyLogic myLogic)
    {
        _myService = myService;
        _myLogic = myLogic;
    }
    #endregion

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // Obtaining string directly from the IMyService
        var sService = _myService.GetMyStringFromDLL();

        // Obtaining string through the IMyLogic
        var sLogic = _myLogic.GetMyString();

        return View(new List<string>() { sService, sLogic} );
    }
}
```

And finally when default action method of the `Home` controller executed the following two lines are displayed:

```
MyService.GetMyStringFromDLL() is called.
MyLogic.GetMyString() -> MyService.GetMyStringFromDLL() is called.
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer and I really appreciate the effort but unfortunately it does not work in my case and maybe that could because of the version I am using for `Unity` or some other thing which I cannot pinpoint. I have tried all the combinations suggested by you and others and it simply does not work. I managed to get it resolved by adding this before I call `GetMyStringFromDLL`: `var sService= DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IMyService>();`. I even tried the `[InjectionConstructor]` attribute since my class has more than one constructor but it still did not work.

Comment: Can you try the above exercise in a non controller class and see if it working ? Basically what I mean is that try to inject the `_myService` and then call `var sService = _myService.GetMyStringFromDLL();` in a non controller class that does not inherit from `Controller` class.

Comment: @Rahul Sharma: But this is exactly that you have in the `Logic` class. The  `Logic` class does not inherit from the `Controller` and it has `var mystring = _myService.GetMyStringFromDLL();` call. Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: Ohh yes, you are right. I do strongly believe that your solution will suffice but in my case it is not working. I will go ahead and award the bounty to you. Thanks again. If you could tell me the version that you are using for `Unity` and `MVC`, that would be great.

Comment: @Rahul Sharma: My test environment is: target version .NET Framework 4.5, `Unity 4.0.1`. I'll be happy to help if you can modify your example to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you please add a default constrictor to your `MyLogic` class: `public MyLogic(){}` and then check if it working?

Comment: @Rahul Sharma: Yes, after adding the default constructor `public MyLogic(){}` it's working too. I see that after call `DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));` the `public MyLogic(IMyService myService)` constructor is called with an instance of the created `MyService` object.

Comment: Strange. It is not working at my end. Something is going on here. I will dive in deeper to see now since I am curious to know why it is not working at my end. Thanks again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226452/discussion-between-jackdaw-and-rahul-sharma).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't worked with Unity since I last did some work on NopCommerce V1.90, however I do remember that whatever you register in your container does come back if you use Resolve on an instance implementing IUnityResolver.

So basically, you registered IMyService, but you'd also have to register IMyLogic - then instead of doing "var logic = new MyLogic();", you'd do "var logic = resolver.Resolve(typeof(IMyLogic));" and then your injected parameters will be resolved according to the dependency injector (or you'd get the proper errors if they were missing).